# What is "use.typekit.net" doing in the header of a page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking at *[this page.](https://github.com/philipwalton/solved-by-flexbox/blob/master/_includes/head.html)*

I can see this in the header. Can someone explain what it does. I can't see any mention of it and what it is used for:

```
  <script class="js-allow-in-head" src="//use.typekit.net/txx2jfv.js"></script>
  <script class="js-allow-in-head">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

thanks

Comment: It loads Typekit font library and tries to initialize it or to do other things (depends on what is the purpose of the method `.load()`). `try{}catch{}` construction catches exceptions (errors) during execution of the code inside of a `try{}` block, so that there will be no messages in error console and other javascript code on the page will not break. URL written in the way of `//site.com/file.js` allows browser to select what to use for the load of file.js - the regular http or https protocol and it depends on the protocol used to open html page with that code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Typekit](https://typekit.com/) is a provider of webfonts. They probably are the only service that benefits from having the script in the head, because it blocks rendering while the fonts download, thus preventing a [FOUT (flash of unstyled text)](http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/6852-controlling-the-flash-of-unstyled-text-or-fout-using-font-events)

The script works by fetching some css files that contain the fonts in base64 encoding.

Answer (score 2):

//use.typekit.net/txx2jfv.js is the script including in the header of page..this file contain some jquery code...The use of that code is to use beautiful FONTS on your page...check the site https://typekit.com/